# How to fix "Detailed Accuracy By Class"? It displays question marks

Tags: weka, prediction

Trainingsset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohc48uo2169zdi0/200214%20AlleJaren2012-2020%20THUISv1.arff?dl=0
Testset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5tkhbyevf6msvce/200214%20Testbestand%20ATP%20Rotterdam.arff?dl=0

[image: Image with output question marks]

Hi everybody,

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with those .arff-files? What is the reason that the output gives question marks instead of figures?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Cor

Answer (score 0):

In your test set, you do not have a winner.  So, you only have predictions of the winner, but "?" for the actuals.

Some options:
1. Just analyze the training set, but let Weka do a training / test split, so you can get a measure of accuracy.
2. Just analyze the training set, but let Weka do 10-fold crossvalidation.

Here's what I get using J48 with standard parameters and 10-fold crossvalidation:

```
Number of Leaves  :     1915

Size of the tree :  1992


Time taken to build model: 2.47 seconds

=== Stratified cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances       14504               64.1543 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances      8104               35.8457 %
Kappa statistic                          0.2832
Mean absolute error                      0.444 
Root mean squared error                  0.477 
Relative absolute error                 88.7915 %
Root relative squared error             95.3947 %
Total Number of Instances            22608     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 0.672    0.389    0.632      0.672    0.651      0.284    0.679     0.654     0
                 0.611    0.328    0.652      0.611    0.631      0.284    0.679     0.643     1
Weighted Avg.    0.642    0.358    0.642      0.642    0.641      0.284    0.679     0.649     

=== Confusion Matrix ===

    a    b   <-- classified as
 7572 3694 |    a = 0
 4410 6932 |    b = 1
```

I'm not saying that's a good model; I'm just using that as an illustration.

Comment: And thanks for posting your data.  This makes it much easier to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm trying to predict the winner of a tennisgame(testset) with the information of the trainingsset (past matches tennis). I'm using the ? in the testset to predict the winner of the tennisgame. What do I have to do to predict the winner and also get the detailed accuracy and the confusion matrix?

Comment: Do this in two passes.  In the first pass, use 10-fold cross-validation (as shown above).  This will give you the accuracy measures and confusion matrix for the model.  In the second pass, with the same model parameters, use the supplied test set as you used in your question.